# Keycloak - .net core 7 jwt auth permission validation error

Tags: json, .net-core, keycloak, openid, identity

I have given the necessary privileges on the user and it clearly stands as follows
**token content I received**

```
{
  "exp": 1676888952,
  "iat": 1676888652,
  "jti": "e9c4cdd9-6ad2-4d26-a031-e5d35bc83439",
  "iss": "http://localhost:2011/realms/TestInventoryRealm",
  "aud": "testcompany-inventory-client",
  "sub": "022a83d1-42e3-40b2-ac11-542d87c5672f",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "testcompany-inventory-client",
  "session_state": "24f85a76-0637-4dd7-8b8c-0ac1ae2afb66",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "default-roles-testcompanyinventoryrealm",
      "Super Role",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "realm-management": {
      "roles": [
        "view-identity-providers",
        "view-realm",
        "manage-identity-providers",
        "impersonation",
        "realm-admin",
        "create-client",
        "manage-users",
        "query-realms",
        "view-authorization",
        "query-clients",
        "query-users",
        "manage-events",
        "manage-realm",
        "view-events",
        "view-users",
        "view-clients",
        "manage-authorization",
        "manage-clients",
        "query-groups"
      ]
    },
    "broker": {
      "roles": [
        "read-token"
      ]
    },
    "testcompany-inventory-client": {
      "roles": [
        "Super Admin Role",
        "Computing Role",
        "uma_protection",
        "Admin Role",
        "User Role"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "view-applications",
        "view-consent",
        "view-groups",
        "manage-account-links",
        "delete-account",
        "manage-consent",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "scopes": [
          "create:company",
          "update:company",
          "get:company",
          "delete:company"
        ],
        "rsid": "f2f036b2-4921-4e2b-9216-996d8cc5a349",
        "rsname": "Company Resource"
      },
      {
        "rsid": "c59c75c9-3bbe-4a1c-8671-71e3d4b975fc",
        "rsname": "Default Resource"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "24f85a76-0637-4dd7-8b8c-0ac1ae2afb66",
  "email_verified": false,
  "name": "test user",
  "preferred_username": "testuser001",
  "given_name": "test",
  "family_name": "user",
  "email": "testuser@gmail.com"
}
```

**app settings**

```
"Keycloak": {
"ServerRealm": "http://localhost:2011/realms/TestCompanyInventoryRealm",
"Metadata": "http://localhost:2011/realms/TestCompanyInventoryRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration",
"ClientId": "testcompany-inventory-client",
"ClientSecret": "faYwQ8ttVGO7R5wxVGrrZDqqPUCgWL7B",
"TokenExchange": "http://localhost:2011/realms/TestCompanyInventoryRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
"Audience": "testcompany-inventory-client",
"PublicKey": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjdT3dINxLFTnY8kxDPqfoh9U+TjUdisjG71RMpD6Wnd0wX64E9HeRaVxwPURDpUokoGVsVD++V8/U4aQRH3AbGzyw+90rKdPQEEAIkO/gcq8/1ppXojFX+qVT3N4/+4h/PPulwYZeO5FYoRoJAR5t4RXln4+ehOT6ShMKE/9Nxm41ijb/aUaOInp0mWO1kodn//qjqs0tZEU4YsOqeqL8ReM0/+IzYHZlyEZ11cjisxtH0fv5XI9y1C6IuRK55Iwf3yzQrDwmGQfuD3gyzs3v+WcGVdMT4e+9/QqE76WPscUwbZMNWwc0nTS4Vm+VXS5uwCcoYnRWHYY+Pw3E5ljGQIDAQAB"
```

}

**program.cs**

I'm starting the project with a definition like below in the main area of the application.

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



    builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ValidateFilterAttribute());
    }).AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreReadOnlyFields = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault | JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    });

    builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

    //Custom FluentValidation
    builder.Services.AddCustomApplicationServices();



    #region Swagger
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "InventoryManagement.API", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 1safsfsdfdfd\"",
        });
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                },
                new string[] {}
            }
        });
    });
    #endregion







    #region JWT
    builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(auth =>
        {
            auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Keycloak:ServerRealm"];
            options.Audience = "testcompany-inventory-client";
            options.IncludeErrorDetails= true;
            options.SaveToken = true; 


            options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Keycloak:ServerRealm"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Keycloak:PublicKey"])),
            };
        });

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(opts =>
    {
        opts.AddPolicy("create:company", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim("scope", new[] { "create:company", "get:company", "update:company", "delete:company" });
        });
    });
    #endregion


    #region Dependencies
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Service<>));
    builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(NotFoundFilter<>));
    builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
    #endregion



    #region Sql Server Connection
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x =>
    {
        x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IMDbConnection"), options =>
        {
            options.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DataContext)).GetName().Name);
        });
    });
    #endregion

    builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
    builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder => containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new RepositoryServiceModule()));





    var app = builder.Build();
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();

    app.UseCustomException();

    app.Run();
```

**CompanyController.cs**

```
  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Roles = "Super Admin Role", Policy = "company")]
  public class CompanyController : CustomBaseController
  { }
```

But even though it's allowed, it doesn't authenticate in any way. Am I missing a place?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you get a 401 error status code, then that typically means that your token was not accepted (Authentication).

If you get a 403 error, then that means that you are not allowed in (Authorization)

One approach to debug this is to set this flag to true in AddJwtBearer:

```
options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
```

If you do that, the WWW-Authenticate header will include why the token was rejected, like:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

Another problem in your code is that you have these two in the wrong order:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

You should always do authentication before authorization. Otherwise it does not make any sense.

If you get 403 Forbiddn errors, then that is caused by the authorization module and to troubleshoot that , I typically create an action method that allows anonymous requests and that just returns the claims found in the user object:

```
      [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("/tokenapi/getidentity")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = new Result();

        if (User != null)
        {
            result.Name = User.Identity?.Name ?? "Unknown Name";
            result.Claims = (from c in User.Claims select c.Type + ":" + c.Value).ToList();
        }

        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

If the scope claim is missing, then you need to explicitly add it to the User object, using something like:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("scope", "scope");
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: yes, I added `options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;` as you said, but it didn't give any details. It keeps returning 401.

Comment: what headers are included in the 401 response?

Comment: ` content-length: 0  date: Mon,20 Feb 2023 11:18:58 GMT  server: Kestrel  www-authenticate: Bearer `

Comment: Are you sure the IncludeErrorDetailsflag is set to true? Also can you add the code in Program.cs that defines the reuqest pipeline? (All the UseXXX methods..

Comment: yes, now I have added all the contents of the program.cs file to the parent topic content. But even though the token content is correct, it does not progress in any way.

Comment: see my updated answer, I found one bug to start with.

Comment: hi, yes i changed it respectively but still not verifying i am getting status code 401. I'm about to go crazy :)

Comment: do you get more details in the WWW-header now after the change?

Comment: added some more debugging tips to my answer

Comment: `app.UseAuthentication();  app.UseAuthorization();` now i add it like this and i get 403 status code. But scopes has the necessary permission.

Comment: good, if you now get 403 errors, at at the actual claims found inside the User object. They might not always be same as the ones found on the token.

Comment: se my updated answer....